# Intensity estimation of the marked process.

Tags: maximum-likelihood, poisson-process

I observe a sample of the form $=[_1,_2,…,_]=[(_1,_1),(_2,_2),…,(_,_)]$ where each $_$ is an arrival time and  is the amount of money spent by the th customer.

I assume that for each amount $$, the arrival times of the filtered sample $=[_:_>]$ follow a homogeneous Poisson process with the intensity $_x=^{−}$.

How do I estimate $$ and $$? Is it correct that $1/=\frac{1}{}∑^_{=1}_$?

Edit: It is easy to estimate  and  by counting the number of events in each $S_x$ for several values of $x$ and fitting a linear regression to the logarithms of these numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that those are *all* arrivals within some time window of known duration $T$, you can try the maximal likelihood estimate. Under your assumptions, the probability density at the observed event will be proportional to $A^NT^Ne^{-AT}k^Ne^{-k\sum_j x_j}$, so, indeed, $\frac 1k=\frac 1N\sum_j x_j$ is a good choice. By the same logic, $A=N/T$ (which is not at all surprising). Of course, these estimates are meaningful only if the model itself is not too far from the truth, but checking that is a completely different issue.

Comment: What you are saying might be correct. I have hard time understanding the independence of arrival times and the $x$'s. It seems to me that under my assumptions they are not independent.

Comment: @VladimirKrouglov I used the model when you just have independent Poisson processes with intensities $Ake^{-kx}dx$ for customers paying between $x$ and $x+dx$ (passing to the limit as $dx\to 0$ at the end), which fits your description though I agree that it might be not *the only* model that fits your description, in which case the question is ambiguous and we may want to specify the model further first.

Comment: @VladimirKrouglov As I said, it would be nice to think of how to test that the model is not too far from the reality before trying to estimate the parameters from the data, but it is a completely different topic :-)

Comment: I guess the only thing I have is that if I plot the intensity of arrivals of customers with $x>y$ as a function of $y$ - it is very well approximated by the exponential curve, i.e. the $log$ of this function is very close to linear.

Comment: and, by the nature of my problem customers who spend the amount $x>y$ come independently.